# Javascript constructor with closure using outside variables referencing other variables

Tags: javascript, closures

```
var Beer = function(){
    var moreBot = 100,
        lessBot = 10,
        wholeCase =  moreBot + lessBot;

    this.count = function(){
        moreBot = 22; 
        lessBot = 33;
        console.log(moreBot); //returns 22
        console.log(lessBot); //returns 33
        return wholeCase; //returns 110 instead of 55??
    };
};

var Alc = new Beer();
```

So say I have this constructor using a closure which references the outside function variables.  Then why is it that when I return wholeCase after changing the variables moreBot and lessBot do I get the sum of the originally assigned values?  Thank you in advance for your expertise!

Comment: You forgot to do `wholeCase = moreBot + lessBot` the second time around. You have to tell JavaScript to do it for you. It won't just figure it out by itself.

Comment: Changing the value of a variable, **never** magically changes the value of another variable. In this aspect, JavaScript behaves like most other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wholeCase` is set at construction time. Your example is not significantly different from:

```
var foo = 5,
    bar = 6;
var sum = foo + bar; // sum is 11

foo = 100000;
console.log(sum); // sum is still 11; we never changed sum
```

You either need to recompute `wholeCase` each time you use it, or just make it a function:

```
var Beer = function(){
    var moreBot = 100,
        lessBot = 10,
        computeWholeCase = function() { return moreBot + lessBot };

    this.count = function(){
        moreBot = 22; 
        lessBot = 33;

        return computeWholeCase(); // run computeWholeCase to return 55
    };
};
```